# Persistent way for getting an Input Value using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner at React. I'm trying to build a component that recovers the text of an input and later on inserts it on the HTML.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function InputGetter(){
    const [text, setText] = useState("")
    let typed = ""
    return(
        <div>
            <input type='text' onChange = {(e)=> typed = e.target.value}></input>
            <button onClick={() => setText(typed)}>Set Text</button>
            Text typed was "{text}"
        </div>
    )
}

export default InputGetter
```

[image: Empty input]

[image]

The code above works for clicks when there's a change triggered. However, when I try to double click it, even when there's content on the input, `text` somehow is set to `""`. I'm not sure why it happens. How can I make the `text`variable content persistent?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on `text` value within the `onClick` callback, to persist value between renders, you can use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook, see [Is there something like instance variables?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables).

```
function InputGetter() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const inputRef = useRef('');
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef}></input>
      <button onClick={() => setText(inputRef.current.value)}>Set Text</button>
      Text typed was "{text}"
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I searched useRef and managed to get it working!

https://pastebin.com/hMnHWN6G

However, your code works but doesn't use the button. Change it so  can mark it as a response!

Comment: Not sure what you doing with the button... The ref seems useless here, you already have `text` value here.

Comment: I'm using `input_ref` for extracting the current input value, and using that value for setting the state of text. Is works as expected (not sure if it's standard though)

Comment: Why not just use the text value as in the answer....

Comment: Because i want the button to trigger the text rendering, not the typing itself!

Comment: Oh ok, you never said that, let me fix it, and yes, thats the best solution (using ref)